# Unable to install tensorflow-compression

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I get this error every time I try to install **tensorflow-compression**

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-compression (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-compression
```

I'm using **python 3.6.8** and **tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0**.

This package does exist and was recently updated:
https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-compression/

I've tried to install it in a **python 2.7** environment, but it didn't work.

Also tried to specify the latest version `pip install tensorflow-compression==1.2`, but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing this, prebuilt wheels of `tensorflow-compression` exist only for Linux/MacOS. Quoting the [readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/compression#installation):

> #### Installation
>
> Note: Precompiled packages are currently only provided for Linux (Python 2.7, 3.3-3.7) and Darwin/Mac OS (Python 2.7, 3.7).
> To use these packages on Windows, consider using a [TensorFlow Docker image](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker) and installing tensorflow-compression using pip inside the Docker container.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is currently not supported. Please use one of TensorFlow's Docker images (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker) and pip install tensorflow_compression there.